# How do I open "Project settings" in Xcode 3.2.5 in a project?

Tags: iphone, xcode

It's assumed that I know where "Project settings" is, but I have no clue.
https://github.com/facebook/three20#readme says: "Finally, we need to tell your project where to find the Three20 headers. Open your "Project Settings" and go to the "Build" tab. Look for "Header Search Paths" and double-click it. Add the relative path from your project's directory to the "three20/Build/Products/three20" directory."

Where is project settings?

Answer (score 5):

You can either:

1. Double-click the project name in the project tree. It's the root object with a blue icon, or
2. Select the project name in the project tree, control/right-click it and choose Get Info, or
3. Go to the Project menu and choose Edit Project Settings.

The project tree is that tree shown to the left of the Xcode window, the one that lists groups and files.

Comment: It didnt work! I want this window (yellow): http://forum.macworld.se/index.php?app=core&module=attach&section=attach&attach_rel_module=post&attach_id=66277

Comment: @Calle That page is only visible to subscribers. Please edit your original question and upload the picture there.

Comment: That is in your mac menu bar. Select the XCode and the top bar should have a "Project" option.

Comment: not valid for latest version xcode version 14 - still looking ...